# Possible to check if Key V is pressed in AddingNewItem event in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Is it possible to check if key V is pressed in the AddingNewItem event in a WPF datagrid similar to how its done in PreviewKeyDown Event

```
private void grd_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.V && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
         //TODO
    }
}
```

I am checking if Ctrl+V is pressed, is it possible to do the same check in addingnewitem event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Keyboard.IsKeyDown()` like this:

```
if (((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.V)))
{
    // CTRL + V is pressed
}
```